# How to configure Three20 Lib so that it displays images of variable width/height

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I'm using the Three20 library to display a photo gallery in my iphone app but the images are getting cut off when I click on them.  Where do I specify in my Three20 lib (or preferably in my call to Three20) what the image dimensions should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the xml feed. It was missing the width and height and once I added it in then Three20 was able to scale the image with the correct dimensions.